# trigger a build on a project when a commit pushes to another project

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have three projects A,B,C on gitlab with a gitlab-runner machine. Project A contains gitlab-ci.yml file which calls a script to build the program when there is a commit on A:

```
  build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./build-platform.sh
```

A depends on B and C projects. How can I trigger a build on A when there is a commit on B or C. I cannot put B,C in A and I cannot convert build-platform.sh to a gitlab-ci.yml file syntax easily.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a couple ways of doing what you want, but they all rely on you going to project A's settings in gitlab and adding a trigger token. This is done through the `<project A's gitlab URL>/settings/ci_cd` page by clicking on `Add trigger` in the **Triggers** section.

You will also find the different ways of using that trigger token from that page.

For the sake of completeness here's a few of the ways mentioned there:

## 1 Using cURL

If you can use curl at the end of the build of projects B or C then simply add the following:

```
curl -X POST \
     -F token=TOKEN \
     -F ref=REF_NAME \
     <gitlab_url>/api/v3/projects/1/trigger/builds
```

Where TOKEN is the trigger token you just generated for project A and REF_NAME is the name of a branch or tag to run the build for.

This can be done if you have automatic builds for projects B and C (using a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file for instance).

## 2 Using a webhook

You can add a webhook to projects B and C through the settings/integrations page of those projects.

Simply add the following webhook on push events:

```
<gitlab_url>/api/v3/projects/1/ref/REF_NAME/trigger/builds?token=TOKEN
```

Where TOKEN and REF_NAME are the same as above.