# Maven projects structure and gitlab

Tags: java, git, maven, dependencies, gitlab

I currently have 4 maven projects, A, B C and D.  A, B and C all depend on D. 
I need these projects to be hosted on gitlab (using gitlab CI).  
Whenever I change any of the above 4 projects, I want to have new jars built from A B and C (automatically build D).
I need this also to work in Gitlab CI.  Is this doable with maven/gitlab?

thanks

Comment: Don't have the references to hand, but what you're looking for is inter-project GitLab dependencies. They're not supported in CI yet, and support doesn't appear in progress, though there are several issues requesting it. You can kinda hack your way around it by using manual self-call triggers.

Comment: It sounds like A, B and C depend on D which in consequence sounds like a multi module build which will solve all the things you have described...

Comment: This might be relevant : http://stackoverflow.com/a/42841567/6654146